# Segfault while passing ostream as reference

Tags: c++

I am writing a code where the output would be either stdout, or a file.  To do so, I found convenient to use `ostream`.  It seems that I do not use it appropriately.  Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <fstream>

struct A {
  std::ostream *os;

  A (const char *fn) {
    std::filebuf fb;
    fb.open (fn, std::ios::out);
    os = new std::ostream(&fb);
  }

  std::ostream &getOS () {
    return *os;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  A a("foo.txt");
  a.getOS() << "bar" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine, but I have a segmentation fault at run time.  Valgrind says `Use of uninitialised value of size 8`, but I cannot interpret it correctly.  Likewise, gdb gives the offending line (call to `a.getOS()`), but I do not know how to correct it.

Comment: Your filebuf fb runs out of scope once the constructor is finished. The ostream then holds a pointer to a destroyed object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Jodocus commented, the variable **std::filebuf fb** is local in the constructor. It will be destroyed when it goes out of scope. The problem can be corrected by defining **std::filebuf fb** as a member variable.

```
#include <fstream>

struct A 
{
    std::ostream *os;
    std::filebuf fb;

    A (const char *fn) 
    {       
        fb.open (fn, std::ios::out);
        os = new std::ostream(&fb);
    }

    std::ostream &getOS () 
    {
        return *os;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    A a("/home/test.txt");
    a.getOS() << "bar" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```